# Two twins - Alike in nature

Tags: riddle, word

Two twins we are, and, let it not surprise,
Alike in every feature, shape, and size:
We’re square, or round, of brass or iron made,
Sometimes of wood, yet useful found in trade ;
But, to conclude, for all our daily pains,
We by the neck are often hung in chains.

What are we?

From The Book of Riddle
Portland: Bailey & Noyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A pair of scales.

Most of the riddle is just describing them, and the last lines allude to their purpose.

*Two twins we are, and, let it not surprise,

Alike in every feature, shape, and size:
We’re square, or round, of brass or iron made,

Sometimes of wood, yet useful found in trade;*

> Scales may be made of various different materials, they consist of two identical parts, and they might be often used by old-time traders.

*But, to conclude, for all our daily pains,

We by the neck are often hung in chains.

Either we're equal or one is greater.*

> They dangle side by side from chains, and whether they're equal or one is greater is the important thing in using them.

Comment: Just beat me! I'll ask @beveloper to give the checkmark to you, and I have answered two of the other riddles the OP posted. +1

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> A pair of scales (to weigh things)

Alike in every feature, shape, and size:

> They have to be the same or their purpose is destroyed.

We’re square, or round, of brass or iron made, Sometimes of wood, yet useful found in trade ;

> They can be made of many things, weighing things is a part of trading.

We by the neck are often hung in chains.

> They are chained up (to function).